# Почему неправильно работает width: 50%?

Tags: html, вёрстка

Всем привет, есть код:

```
<table border = 1>
<tr>
<th style = "width: 50%"><img src = "тут типо картинка" width = 100 height = 100/></th>
<th>YANDEX.RU - это Яндекс</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

Я прочитал, что "правильно" делать хедеры, нужно через таблицу, но беда в том, что когда я применяю стиль, где указываю, что длина ячейки будет 50% от длины страницы, он почему-то применяет это событие ко второму <th>. Да я ещё кое-что, почему везде 100% - это длина всех страницы, а 1% это самое маленькое число. А тут наоборот 1% - это длина всех страницы, а 100% - это очень маленький кусочек?

Comment: Интересно, я один, кто ничего не понял?

Comment: "Так вот я прочитал, что "правильно" делать хедеры, нужно через таблицу, ..." -можно ссылку?! Насколько мне известно, сейчас таблицы используются только для отображения табличных данных. Я, если честно, мало что понял. Делайте все через `<div>` без таблиц.

Comment: Блочно, блочно и только блочно. Не умеете верстать учите по новым книгам, новым статьям. НЕ ЧИТАЙТЕ СТАРЬЕ!!!
БЛОЧНО!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Нечего не понял, буду действовать по интуиции. Для начала, неужели так сложно писать "культурный код". Почему значение атрибутов не закреплено между "". `<table border = "1">`.
Теперь по теме: не вижу смысла юрзать в данном таблицу. Используйте `<div>`
**Пример:**

```
<div><img src = "тут типо картинка" style="width:100px; height:100px; float: left;" alt=""/>YANDEX.RU - это Яндекс</div>
```

Кстати, когда вы пишите width='50%', то 50% от родителя, родителем может быть в вашем случае как table, так и body.

Comment: зачем див в потоке, у человека сейчас будет куча проблем из-за этого, зачем блочному элементу писать 100%, ведь он и так расстягивается на всю доступную ему ширину